# Cruisecontrol.net to deploy msi

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to deploy an MSI to remote server and run database script on sql server using CruiseControl.net? I am new to CruiseControl.Net and looking for an example.

I tried the below wiki page but deployment page is under construction:

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have CruiseControl.net call either PowerShell or Batch file. More info on the CruiseControl.net config to call PowerShell or Batch file can be found [here](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Executable%20Task.html).

From the PowerShell or Batch file you can use [PSExec](http://forum.sysinternals.com/remote-install-of-msi-packages-using-psexec_topic22970.html) to install MSI file for a remote server. As for running database scripts on remote server you can use [SqlCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) .